# YA book 90s-early 00s a young girl attends a magic school, cover art brown haired girl and bubbles?

Tags: story-identification

I remember a chapter book for middle school aged kids, I don't remember much about it but what I do remember is a girl attends a magic boarding school, I think there is a shapeshifter involved, like a student or something. All I remember is at the end there are multiple dimensions and the version of herself in that dimension dies but another lives? And there is some evil involved. The cover art is yellow, with a brown haired girl and bubbles all around her that contain images. Please help me, I can't for the life of me remember what this book is called!!

It was definitely English, either American or British.

Comment: Please mention Language of the book, Country of Origin if you remember. That might help.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178084/book-id-girl-who-steals-magic-from-her-reflections (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

Adapted from [this answer to another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/100746/4495),

I found *[A School for Sorcery](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765342197)* by E. Rose Sabin.

[image: The cover does have bubbles]

From one review on the Amazon page:

> Tria, the heroine of A School for Sorcery, is faced with an outsized tussle: her elegant, spiteful roommate has a habit of turning into a black panther at times of stress (...)

And

> It's a depressing tale about manipulating adults, evil children, and multiple dimensions.

Comment: By the way, my answer to the other question was not accepted. If this turns out to be it, can this one still be closed as a duplicate, or does the other one need to be accepted as well?

Comment: Generally speaking, both have to be accepted. Richard was taking steps in the other direction but... oh my, maybe that's why he was kicked out, because he was challenging the status quo! :)

Comment: Read through the book. Definitely a match.